# Function to change the text inside a paragraph selected by id

Tags: javascript, html

I have this paragraph in HTML:

```
<p id="paragraph">text</p>
```

I wrote a function to change the text inside paragraphs. I want two variables: the id of the paragraph and the text.

```
function changeInnerText(id, text) 
{
  const place = document.getElementById(`${id}`);
  place.innerText = `${text}`;
}
```

It doesn't work, how do I fix it?

Comment: [Fix it by yourself](https://www.tutorialkart.com/javascript/how-to-change-text-in-paragraph-using-javascript/)

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for...

Comment: It's a very basic thing. I believe you haven't even tried to solve it yourself.

Comment: I can do it without using arguments on the function. I'm a beginner. No problem if you don't want to help me.

Answer (score 1):

It works as long as you call the function correctly.

```js
function changeInnerText(id, text) {
  const place = document.getElementById(`${id}`);
  place.innerText = `${text}`;
}

changeInnerText("paragraph", "i was changed")
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">text</p>
```